# DJANGO POSTGRES matching query does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

Hi i have a seller model that is related one to one field with user in DJANGO. Seller can create a "deal" and to become seller you first have to create a normal account as a user.
I dont have any idea how to take to the view deals that are from the specyfic seller

MY views.

```
@user_passes_test(is_seller)
def seller_page(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        user = request.user
        _seller = Seller.objects.get(user_id=user)  # TODO: doesnt work
        deals = Deal.objects.get(seller_id=_seller)
        form = forms.DealModelForm
        context = {'deals': deals, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'seller_page.html', context)
```

My models

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bank_account = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nip = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_seller_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sells = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Deal(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    is_deal_on = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    sell_price = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, help_text='Cena sprzedaży')
    origin_price = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, help_text='Oryginalna cena',
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    time_valid = models.IntegerField(default=12)  # ilość miesięcy ile warty jest deal
    unique_code = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    province = models.IntegerField(choices=PROVINCES)
```

ERROR :

_seller = Seller.objects.get(user_id=user)

Answer (score 1):

If the "user" variable is an integer:

```
_seller = Seller.objects.get(user__id=user) #Note that is "__" and not "_"
```

if the "user" variable is an object (User model):

```
_seller = Seller.objects.get(user=user)
```